# Shell, multiple directories format doesn't work

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, mkdir

today I tried to do multiple directories on one line in the terminal but something is wrong with it, as the sell reads the name of the directories literally and instead of getting n directories I end up with one. I used this format:

`mkdir foldername8.{2...5}`

I tried also:

`mkdir ./foldername8.{2...5}`,
though I was in the right directory and the first time. 
Instead of obtaining foldername8.2, foldernamer8.3... -//-.5 I get 1 folder named foldername8.{2...5}

I tried the same without the dot after 8, it still doesn't do anything. I tried wrapping everything up from the beginning once in curly brackets, and then the same - takes it literally. How can I do it with relatively short amount of code? I'm running on Mint Cinnamon, the last version.

Comment: It's a typo. Use two dots, not three: `mkdir foldername8.{2..5}`. Also note that it works in `bash`, `zsh` and similar but not `sh`.

Comment: Oh, you aided my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 
   `mkdir [directorie 1] && mkdir [directorie 2] && mkdir [directorie n]`
```